# How can I view the actual amount of close votes

Tags: support, review

I recently thought that I would have a look at the Close vote queue *(since I usually never bother - I have been trying to  have a go at the moment)*. When I was finished it looked like this:

> [image: 0 close votes in the queue]

So I thought 'great!' - but doesn't this not include the ones I have already reviewed? So how can I view *all* the Close votes still in the queue, including the ones that I have already reviewed, but still need to be reviewed by other users? *(N.B. preferably without logging out)*

Comment: There's also [this](http://askubuntu.com/review/close/history), but I doubt that is what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this thing called private session, or window... or whatever. This is how it looks:

[image]

You can also query the database, but is not real time. I'm sure the API also has this information.

Comment: That was quick... I forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

@Braiam's answer has probably the simplest way to do this - this gave me the idea anyway of modifying a rubbish bash script I have, and I ended up with this:

```
curl -s http://askubuntu.com/review | grep -i -m 1 -B 6 "close votes" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>\|[^0-9.k]//g' -e '/^$/d'
```

I tested it here and on SO (which the massive close review queue, why `.k` is needed...) - I could probably improve it but I think I have better things to do :D

N.B. you need to put 'close votes', 'suggested' etc, as just 'close','suggest' will pick up the inpage javascript and generate a load of junk.